# How to run android apps in emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I've a problem that whenever I run my application in emulator in second time then  it can not load on emulator and showing **"Launching...?27%"** and then it stop on 27%.then I have to restart eclips and again second time same thing happen.I'm working on android lin mac machine. please some one help me.

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in Android Logcat? If so, please provide them.

Comment: No there is no error in log cat.in second time the compilation is not completed. it stop on 27%.

Comment: Sorry Adil I don't understand wt u mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got that problem and I think it's some sort of Bug.

Well, the best choice I've got is to Start the emulator manually (via AVD Manager > Choose emulator > Start...) and minimizing it's Window. When you Run your application, it'll open it in the already started emulator and you're good to go. :)

If it shows the Window for you to choose a connected phone or an emulator, it'll show the emulator instance as a connected phone.

Since the emulator takes a while to start, I believe it's the most rapid way to work with it, so I've take it as the "right" way...

Comment: PS: It's not a Mac issue, I've got it on Windows also.